# Difference between xreadlines and for-looping a file

Tags: python, file

Having a file object in Python 2.7:

```
f = open('my_file', 'r')
```

What would be the difference between for-looping the file (most common way) and using the `xreadlines()` function:

```
for line in f:
    # Do something with line
```

and

```
for line in f.xreadlines():
    # Do something with line
```

I mean, both options define a generator, in contrast to the `readlines()` or `read()` functions that loads all the file content to memory.

Is there some performance or file-handling improvment in any of them? Or they are just to equivalent ways of doing the same thing?

Comment: `xreadlines` came first. In general Python started with list-based functions (`range`, `items`, `zip`), introduced iterator counterparts (`xrange, `iteritems`, `izip`) and then changed the original functions to return iterators. This is the tail end of one of those changes.

Comment: Note also that `for _ in something` will call `iter(something)` behind-the-scenes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=xreadlines#file.xreadlines)

```
file.xreadlines()
This method returns the same thing as iter(f).

New in version 2.1.

Deprecated since version 2.3: Use for line in file instead.
```

... and it's better to use the `with` keyword when working with files; again see the docs page.

```
with open('my_file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: so it means that they are perfectly and exactly the same!